# What is wrong with my WHERE condition in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, string-constant

I am running the query `SELECT * FROM app_user WHERE login_id = "john";` and getting -

```
ERROR:  column "john" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.app_user WHERE login_id = "john";
                                                       ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 48
```

I have also tried `SELECT * FROM public.app_user WHERE login_id = "john";` and I still get the same error.

The same error also occurs with any other column but the id column(id is the only non-VARCHAR column and is the primary key).

So, `SELECT * FROM app_user WHERE id = 5;` is working as expected .

A snapshot of the table follows.

[image: Snapshot of the table]

Comment: what happens if you use single-quotes for `john`?

Comment: Yes, single quotes solve this for me. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 1):

If you write the  string in double quotes, postgres will interpret it as a column name in the WHERE clause, just use single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM public.app_user WHERE login_id = 'john';
```